# PHP substring() start from last duplicate of word

Tags: php

I have big .txt file. What I need to do is format it, to be able to see only specific part from document.

```
$findFrom = 'Word 1';
$findTo = 'Word 2';
$start = strpos($content, $findFrom);
$end = strpos($content, $findTo);
substr($content, $start, $end);
```

Word 1 is used 2 times in .txt file, I need to start substring() from 2nd not the first one. No idea, how to do it.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php

Comment: @dev0 please correct your link with english version

Comment: @HalayemAnis you can change language on page. It is in English

Answer (score 0):

If you know position of the first occurrence of `Word 1` - then do another `strpos` for `Word 1` using `offset` parameter, something like:

```
// first occurrence of Word 1
$start = strpos($content, $findFrom); 
// set offset to start from previously found position plus one
$start = strpos($content, $findFrom, $start + 1); 
$end = strpos($content, $findTo);
substr($content, $start, $end);
```

Comment: Done it. Thanks. How about replacing specific part from document with     "space" ? str_replace() can do It only on words, but how I can do it on parts? For ex. I have text: "I gotta Power yeeeah" and I want to replace gotta Power with spaces.

Comment: `str_replace(' gotta Power  ', '_', $str)`?